# Reliably tail/stream a log file to another machine (Keyword: Reliably). Strangely impossible?

Tags: linux, unix, rsync, solaris, syslog

I have a growing logfile on a unix box. I just want something that collects that data on another box within a few seconds of it being written.

Sounds simple. But I need it to not introduce screw ups if :

1. either box reboots
2. the network glitches
3. the logfile is rotated (no need to lose data with a filehandle open on both)
4. handling the above causes undetectable data duplication (since the filename/inode/seekpoint/trunccount are available, duplication is detectable)
5. (Optional) the file is truncated (return to start, mention to peer - small window of potential unavoidable data loss).

I can't seem to find anything that does this right. *syslog-ng* and *nxlog* want money to avoid problem 2. *rsyslog* gives itself problem 1 when it faces problem 2, and ate my CPU in testing.

There seems to be no tool that doesn't create more problems than it solves.

Comment: Syslog-ng as far as i'm aware is free, and will do logging over the network so why can't you just setup a 2nd destination and add it?

Comment: Because the syslog-ng librelp equiv module [is not free](https://syslog-ng.org/question/is-relp-supported-by-syslog-ng-or-is-there-another-protocol-that-support-reliable-message-delivery-compatible-with-rsyslog/). I need a protocol that ACKs data receipt.